# Why is it not good/common practice to place a comma before 'for'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I've written a book which has the following line:

> It is this curse which has brought many sleepless nights upon me, for one’s egotistical ambition to be certain of one’s knowledge is the precursor for dissatisfaction and dissociation.

The proof reader/editor left a comment on it, noting that it's not good/common practice to have a comma before **for** when used as an alternative for **because.**

Is this true? If so, why not?

Comment: You'll have to ask your proof reader.

Comment: I would disagree.  Without the comma, I'm inclined to see "for" as introducing a prepositional phrase rather than a subordinate clause.  I find it more easily readable with the comma.

Comment: I also disagree with your proofreader. Reads fine to me.

Comment: Judging by the answers, this seems to be a case of a (supposed, disputed) grammar-book rule being put ahead of clear and readable writing.  Well, personally, [this is the sort of English up with which I will not put](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25805/up-with-which-i-will-not-put).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was "scandalised" to find information in favour of your proofreader's opinion! On the [ProWritingAid site](https://prowritingaid.com/grammar/1008101/Should-I-use-a-comma-before-for-) I found this explanation:

> Sometimes "***for***" can be used as a subordinating conjunction in place of
> "***because***". If it starts a dependent clause after the main clause, **it
> shouldn't be preceded by a comma**:
>
> She bought more gloves for she was always losing them.
>
> However, if the
> independent clause that comes before "***for***" contains ***a negative verb***,
> you need a comma:
>
> He didn't take his umbrella, for the rain had stopped that afternoon.

On another [site](https://pwntestprep.com/2016/04/when-do-we-use-a-comma-before-for/#:%7E:text=When%20%E2%80%9Cfor%E2%80%9D%20is%20used%20as,other%20structure%20that%20needs%20commas.) I found a more determined "pro comma" opinion:

> When “for” is used as a conjunction between two clauses (“for” is the
> F in FANBOYS) then you need a comma before it. When it’s used as a
> preposition (e.g., some flowers for my mom) you probably don’t need a
> comma before it, unless it’s in a list or some other structure that
> needs commas.

I also found a rule on the [PurdueWritingLab](https://owl.purdue.edu/engagement/ged_preparation/part_1_lessons_1_4/commas.html) about FOR linking two independent clauses:

> Use a comma before a conjunction (and, but, for, nor, or, so, and yet)
> to join two independent clauses.

AND

> Use commas to separate independent clauses when they are joined by any
> of these seven coordinating conjunctions: and, but, for, or, nor, so,
> yet.

So I presume it is finally a matter of deciding if FOR links an independent clause to a dependent one, or two independent clauses.

Here is the guideline I would personally follow:

> A comma always comes before the fanboys when they introduce an
> independent clause or a complete thought. However, if the fanboys in a
> sentence do not connect two complete ideas, then we do not use a comma
> in front of them.

([ius.edu/writing-center site](https://www.ius.edu/writing-center/files/fanboys-and-wabbits.pdf))

Note: FANBOYS is made up of the initials of the seven coordinating conjunctions: For, And, Nor, But, Or, Yet, So.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1):

I would much rather see a comma before the "for" in that usage. The comma to me would mark the distinction between effect and causation, and the pause is mirrored by actual speech: speaking that line aloud, I would naturally insert the pause to separate the two clauses.

Without the comma, the reader easily mistakes "for" as being part of "sleepless nights upon me for", where "for" is a preposition potentially followed by "x number of years" or the likes. When the sentence then continues with "one’s egotistical ambition to be certain of one’s knowledge is the _____", the reader is jolted out of that interpretation and must go back and try to make sense of the sentence.

I would recognize "for" as a word that starts sentences/clauses that imply causation, and that comma tells me as the reader that "for" is the first word of a clause rather than a preposition. The clause can grammatically hold its own as a sentence. It gets a comma, whereas omitting the comma signals that the following is not valid as a complete grammatical sentence. Interfering with this convention disrupts the writing.